# Sequence of tenses with past perfect

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

if a first sentence is in the past perfect and a second is in the same time with a first should a first be in past perfect too or in past simple?
E.g: Alex said he had been there when that happened or Alex said he had been there when that had happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In native English you will hear both, simply depending the personal preference of the speaker and on the context.

I suspect most speakers would omit the second **had** for the sake of brevity and because its omission makes no difference to the meaning.

So an army officer might say **that he had been there when the victory had been secured**, especially if it was a long time ago.

Here you might argue that the use of the past perfect gives listeners a sense of the period. But **was secured** is equally correct.

And a witness might say **that she had been there when the bus overturned**, preferring the simple past, especially if it's a recent event and if the bus is still lying on its side.

In short, this isn't a question of correctness but of choice.

Comment: Can you give some references on grammar sources can explain this rule of omission?

Comment: @PetroProbka No I can't. I based my answer on 70 years' experience of learning, speaking, writing, teaching and broadcasting in my native language.